# Fix circular reference in symfony when using SerializerInterface

Tags: symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I'm getting a circular reference error when serializing a component. Usually this can be fixed using

```
$normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler()
```

However, I'm using the SerializerInterface like this:

```
/**
  * @Route("/get/{id}", name="get_order_by_id", methods="GET")
  */
 public function getOrderById(SerializerInterface $serializer, OrderRepository $orderRepository, $id): Response
 {
   return new Response($serializer->serialize(
     $orderRepository->find($id),
     'json',
     array('groups' => array('default')))
   );
  }
```

Is it possible to fix a circular reference error when serializing using this interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You totally can. Just add this in your framework config.

```
framework:
    serializer:
        circular_reference_handler: App\Serializer\MyCustomCircularReferenceHandler
```

This handler will work globally. Make sure you register it as a service. I does not need to implement any interface. So just a class with an `__invoke()` will suffice. That invoke will receive the object that is being "circle referenced" as the only argument.

You can either return the id or do some really cool stuff, like creating a uri for the resource. But the implementation details are totally up to you, as long as you don't return the same object, everything will be fine.

:)

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Symfony API Reference](https://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Serializer/SerializerInterface.html) on the interface there doesn't look to be a way to execute that function or retrieve the normalizer.

Even in the [Serializer](https://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Serializer.html), there doesn't look to be a way to retrieve the normalizer after creating the serializer.

You're best off creating the normalizer before the serializer to achieve this, rather than injecting the interface via config files. ([Relevant docs link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html))